# SOMAR STRING como DATE - Oracle

Tags: oracle, data

Tenho a coluna *TEMPO* com tipo `STRING` e preciso somar os valores como horas.
Utilizei todo tipo de query para fazer essa soma, mas sempre caio no problema do campo com o DATATYPE `DATE` não aceitar valores maiores do que *23:59:59*.

Como fazer isso via query no oracle?

**TIME_AVG**

```
42:12:57  
null  
98:31:06  
20:16:12  
04:00:31  
05:18:39  
05:18:06  
50:09:12  
22:59:27  
null  
25:39:39  
25:20:27  
42:12:57  
null  
98:31:06  
20:16:12  
04:00:31
```

Comment: De mais detalhes, o que voce tentou fazer qual foi o resultado e o que você esperava

Comment: Concordo. Tem de dar mais detalhes. O que é que quer fazer com esse tipo de informação? Quer apenas somar esses valores? Se for esse o caso, claro que não dá para trabalhar com o tipo DATE. Tem de continuar a ser string. Se for esse o caso, a única coisa que me lembro, é trabalhar a string.

Comment: Qual o resultado que espera com essa soma?

Comment: Po caras me desculpe, primeira vez que uso aqui e é falta de costume. Então preciso dessa soma para fazer uma sumarização de dados devido a uma regra de negócio que preciso desenvolver.
Após a soma eu preciso dividir por um outro campos que vou fazer um count(*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para somar essas STRINGS você pode transforma-las em segundos assim:

Como exemplo estou somando a primeira e segunda linha de sua questão.

```
SELECT ( SUBSTR( '42:12:57', 1, 2 ) * 3600 )  + 
       ( SUBSTR( '42:12:57', 1, 2 ) * 60 ) + 
         SUBSTR( '42:12:57', 7, 2 ) + 
       ( SUBSTR( '98:31:06', 1, 2 ) * 3600 )  + 
       ( SUBSTR( '98:31:06', 1, 2 ) * 60 ) + 
         SUBSTR( '98:31:06', 7, 2 ) AS SEGUNDOS 
FROM DUAL
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E para transformar esses segundos na string resultante para armazena-la no 
banco, faça assim:

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(512463/3600),'FM9900') || ':' ||
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(512463,3600)/60),'FM00') || ':' ||
    TO_CHAR(MOD(512463,60),'FM00') AS MEDIA
FROM DUAL
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Creio que com isso você poderá criar uma função facilmente.

Um exemplo de script para somar todos os valores da coluna TIME_AVG da tabela.

```
DECLARE
  SEGUNDOS NUMERIC( 15, 0 );
  TEMP     NUMERIC( 15, 0 );
BEGIN
 SEGUNDOS := 0;
 FOR REC IN ( SELECT TIME_AVG FROM TABELA  ) 
 LOOP
   SELECT ( SUBSTR( REC.TIME_AVG, 1, 2 ) * 3600 )  + 
          ( SUBSTR( REC.TIME_AVG, 1, 2 ) * 60 ) + 
            SUBSTR( REC.TIME_AVG, 7, 2 ) INTO TEMP  FROM DUAL;
   SEGUNDOS := SEGUNDOS + TEMP;
 END LOOP;
 .... RETORNA O VALOR 
END;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, @Reginaldo Rigo, e como faço para dividir o resultado da soma por qualquer número?
Essa minha pergunta é pq preciso fazer essa soma e depois dividir um count(*) de outra coluna.

Comment: Eu dei algumas opções de como fazer isso, porém a aplicação ficaria a seu cargo porque você tem todas as informações. Para eu te ajudar preciso que edite sua pergunta e poste exatamente o que precisa e o que você tem.