# Somando Horas maior 24 h

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, time

A instrução sql me retorna as horas do tipo Time:

```
| Horas  |
|20:52:00|
|12:42:00|
|09:00:00|
|07:45:00|
```

Gostaria de somar o total de horas, mas dessa forma ele esta "zerando" quando chega a 24 horas.

```
procedure ....
var
  vqtMaqLigada : TTime;
begin
while Horas.eof do 
 vqtMaqLigada := vqtMaqLigada + HorasValor;

end;
```

Comment: Qual banco de dados?

Comment: Não deve utilizar TTime, mas sim TTimeSpan. TTime refere-se a uma hora especifica do dia. TTimeSpan aplica-se a uma duração.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiago, você precisa de uma função que transforme a string em segundos,
tipo essa:

```
function GetSeconds(ATimeString: string): Integer;
var
  Hour, Min, Sec, MSec: Word;
begin
  DecodeTime(StrToTime(ATimeString), Hour, Min, Sec, MSec);
  Result := Hour * 3600 + Min * 60 + Sec;
end;
```

Desse modo você pode somar os segundos contidos nas várias strings. 
Depois você pode transformar o numero de segundos em string novamente.

```
  function SecondToTime(const Seconds: Cardinal): Double; 
var 
  ms, ss, mm, hh, dd: Cardinal; 
begin 
  dd := Seconds div SecPerDay; 
  hh := (Seconds mod SecPerDay) div SecPerHour; 
  mm := ((Seconds mod SecPerDay) mod SecPerHour) div SecPerMinute; 
  ss := ((Seconds mod SecPerDay) mod SecPerHour) mod SecPerMinute; 
  ms := 0; 
  Result := dd + EncodeTime(hh, mm, ss, ms); 
end;
```

Se você estiver usando o Oracle poderá somar usando as funções do banco mesmo.

[SOMAR STRING como DATE - Oracle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164329/somar-string-como-date-oracle/164356?noredirect=1#comment339806_164356)

http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/strings/format_seconds_as_hhmmss.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420818/convert-hhmmss-to-seconds-or-minutes-with-delphi

Comment: Porque se assume que os dados são string? O problema não parece ser esse!

Answer (score 0):

O tipo `TTime` é utilizado para representar uma **hora** específica. Se você quer representar um **período de tempo** você deve escolher outras opções. 
Pensei em pelo menos duas:

1. Utilizar `TTimeSpan` - que conforme a [documentação](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TimeSpan.TTimeSpan) foi criado para descrever um intervalo de tempo. Neste caso terá que utilizar os métodos deste objeto para trabalhar com o valor;
2. Utilizar um inteiro comum - Desta forma você poderá armazenar o tempo sem ter que fazer conversões;

De cabeça fiz um exemplo utilizando a primeira opção:

```
procedure ....
var
  TempoMaqLigadaTotal : TTimeSpan;
begin
  //Inicializando o tempo;

  TempoMaqLigadaTotal := TTimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
  while tblHoras.eof do
  begin 
   TempoMaqLigadaTotal.Add(TTimeSpan.FromSeconds(HorasValorEmSegundos));
  end;

  ShowMessage(Format('Ficou ligada por "%d dias, %d horas, %d minutos e %d segundos"', 
              [TempoMaqLigadaTotal.Days, TempoMaqLigadaTotal.Hours, 
               TempoMaqLigadaTotal.Minutes, TempoMaqLigadaTotal.Seconds]));
end;
```